# Python Kivy make scatter unselectable

Tags: python, animation, widget, kivy, scatter

I am making animations in my Kivy app, but of all available classes, only scatter seems to animate properly. The problem is, when I touch the scatter, my on_touch_move() event simply doesn't work. I wanted to make unselectable scatter with

```
self.do_rotation = False
self.do_scale = False
self.do_translation = False
```

but this doesn't seem to work. The scatter is not moving, as expected, but it still can be selected. Or maybe there is a class that animates properly? I've tried Image, AsyncImage, Widget and Layouts. Any ideas?

@EDIT: Here is the simplest example of what am I talking about:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle

class ExampleWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = (100,100)
        self.pos = (100,100)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1,0,0)
            self.texture = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)

    def on_pos(self, obj, value):
        try: self.texture.pos = value
        except: pass

class ExampleScatterTexture(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleScatterTexture, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0,1,0)
            texture = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)

class ExampleScatter(Scatter):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleScatter, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.do_rotation = False
        self.do_scale = False
        self.do_translation = False
        self.size = (100,100)
        self.pos = (100,300)
        texture = ExampleScatterTexture(size=self.size)
        self.add_widget(texture)

class ExampleScreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = Window.size

        example_widget = ExampleWidget()
        self.add_widget(example_widget)

        example_scatter = ExampleScatter()
        self.add_widget(example_scatter)

        #SCATTER IS GREEN, WIDGET IS RED
        example_widget_animation = Animation(pos=(300,100), duration=2., t='in_bounce') + Animation(pos=(100,100), duration=2., t='in_bounce')
        example_scatter_animation = Animation(pos=(300,300), duration=2., t='in_bounce') + Animation(pos=(100,300), duration=2., t='in_bounce')
        example_widget_animation.repeat = True
        example_scatter_animation.repeat = True
        example_widget_animation.start(example_widget)
        example_scatter_animation.start(example_scatter)

class BadAnimationExample(App):
    def build(self):
        root = ExampleScreen()
        return root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BadAnimationExample().run()
```

Comment: Every widget animates properly if you're animating a property which exists on that widget.

Comment: What I am doing with widget is I am adding an image to it and calling on_pos() function to change image position each time widget position is changing like this: self.image.pos = self.pos. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post some working example code that demonstrates the problem. My first guess is that the widget pos never changes, perhaps because it is in a layout that you haven't accounted for, but it's impossible to know without a full example.

Comment: I have no problem with widget moving, my problem is that animation objects for every class except scatter are completely ignoring the transition attribute, that is what I called an improper animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The trick was not to make scatters unselectable, but to use the on_touch_move() method not on my child class, but on parent class.